# SQL Server: Configuring Email Notification when last backup and log backup runs are more than one day behind

Tags: sql-server

Abit of background on the problem, currently all the DB are hooked up to a 3rd party tool for cloud backup and storage. So there are no active backup jobs in the DB server but the tool will trigger and get the backup from the DB. So when I check each DB properties, it would reflect the last DB and log DB backup time

Currently I have been using the script below to manually check the Backup and Log backup last runs.

```
SELECT  
CONVERT(CHAR(100), SERVERPROPERTY('Servername')) AS Server, 
msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name,
CASE msdb..backupset.type 
WHEN 'D' THEN 'Database' 
WHEN 'L' THEN 'Log' 
END AS backup_type,
MAX(msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date) AS last_db_backup_date
FROM msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily  
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset ON msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.media_set_id = msdb.dbo.backupset.media_set_id 
GROUP BY 
msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name,
msdb.dbo.backupset.type
ORDER BY  
msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name,
msdb.dbo.backupset.type
```

I've already configured the my database email but need a way to trigger me an email only when the backup and log backup time is more than a day behind.

Comment: You could use [sp_send_dbmail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#b-sending-an-e-mail-message-with-the-results-of-a-query) to send an email with the query results via T-SQL. You need to first configure [Database Mail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/database-mail/database-mail?view=sql-server-ver15). Add date criteria to the query (perhaps inserting into a temp table) and send the email conditionally only when needed.

Comment: And schedule script execution via a daily SQL Agent job.